# Scheduled LocalNotification in iOS not seen in scheduledLocalNotifications straight away

Tags: ios

The problem I am encountering is that I successfully schedule a local notification for between 1 and 2 hours from now, I then go back to my main root view controller where some code runs and displays a different box depending on whether a local notification is scheduled or not. So the code is:

```
/// Commit notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"exitToStart" sender:self];
```

And then on the main root controller a method is called straight away on return to refresh the view that contains:

```
NSArray *currentNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

if ([currentNotifications count] > 0)
{
   ...
}
else { ... }
```

The problem I am having is that sometimes currentNotifications count is 0 and sometimes it is 1 and so the wrong box is displayed. I think what is happening is sometimes iOS is still scheduling the notification and sometimes it is not, assuming it does it in the background without blocking the thread?

I know the local notification always gets there because if I come in and out of root when the problem occurs then it always finds the local notification.

Is there a way I can wait for it to be scheduled before looking for notifications? That complies with Apple's guidelines. Within the if block I go on to use info from the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see a way to guarantee that by the time I was back in main controller, the notification would always be scheduled. So to get around this I pass back the information I put into the local notification myself to the main controller in its return method. Later returns to the main controller from other areas then have given the local notification the 1 or 2 seconds it needs to schedule itself and can use the existing logic.